# Controller splitting ViewBag model into multiple pages with database parameters is skipping records

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Summary:** Separating a list of Services into multiple pages by a page limit is losing a record in between the two pages.  The second page starts from the same ID regardless of change using Razor.  In other words, I need Page 2 to pick up where Page 1 ends.  This is probably a basic ASP.net issue.  The controller is breaking up the views wrong.

I have inherited a project, and am unable to find where the parameters are set for a View.  I am unable to determine which element is causing the problem and will need guidance as to what code specifically to include beyond what's included.  I will revise the question with the code or other specifics upon receiving comments in an effort to keep the question only as detailed as necessary.

**update NOTE:**  I have no folder named Controllers in the project.  References to the database are found in 'bin\work1.dll'

**Expectation:**
There are two Wall Displays, each with an internal webpage listing "Services", much like an airport terminal lists flight times.  The resolution on the screen is ideal for 5 Services.

There is a SQL table with parameters to define "WallSortBy" and amount of "ServicesPerPage".

By changing the value of ServicesPerPage from 6 to 5, "WallDisplay1" should display Services 1-5 and "WallDisplay2" 6-10, or if there are less than 10 total services, just 6-[Last Service].  If there are more than 10, after the "Countdown" reaches 60 seconds, the pages would cycle with Wall1[6-10], Wall2[11-15], and so on or something to that effect.

**Problem:**
Given 9 Total Services for example. (true with other totals as well)
When ServicesPerPage is changed from 6 to 5:

```
WallDisplay1 = [1 to 5]
WallDisplay2 = [7 to 9]
```

Service 6 is missing.

Set ServicesPerPage to ANYTHING:

```
WallDisplay1 = [1 to ANYTHING]
WallDisplay2 = [7 to 9]
```

**Dashboard:**
The Dashboard is working fine, using the same View layout as the Wall Displays for each "Service"
All 9 Records show there correctly.

**WallDisplay1:**
[image: WallDisplay1]
**WallDisplay2:**
[image: WallDisplay2]

I have searched through the entire project for hard coded 6's and 7's, and have found none.  I can't see any references to the SQL table that stores the parameters by the name of the table. (update: in the bin\work1.dll there are multiple references) .
The connection string in the web.config has the database, but the table name isn't anywhere I can find, in the entire project.  Neither is "ServicesPerPage", and the id for that parameter in the SQL table is a hash id.

The examples I've read on binding models don't have multiple pages split into separate web pages, usually the examples are using a navigator to display the pages from a single web page.

The ViewBag is sorted by "Location", meaning the location of the service not to be confused with the property "windows.location".

There are three Razor .vbhtml pages that use the ViewBag with the Service list: 
Dashboard.vbhtml,
WallDisplay1.vbhtml,
WallDisplay2.vbhtml

**Relevant Dashboard Code:**

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of work1.Service)

@code
    ViewData("Title") = "Board"

    Dim lstServiceStatus As SelectList
    lstServiceStatus = New SelectList(ViewBag.lstServiceStatus, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.viewStatus)

     Dim SortBy As String = If(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("SortBy") Is Nothing, "Location", _
                               HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("SortBy"))
     Dim viewStatus As String = If(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("viewStatus") Is Nothing, "Active", _
                                  HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString("viewStatus"))

End Code

<div id="divBoard">
    <div style="margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;">
        <div style="display:inline-table; margin:0px 0px 4px 0px">
            Sort by: 
            @If ViewBag.sortby = "Date" Then
                @Html.ActionLink("Location", "Dashboard", New With {.SortBy = "Location", .viewStatus = viewStatus})
                @<span style="font-weight:bold">/ Date</span> 
            Else
                @<span style="font-weight:bold">Location /</span> 
                @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Dashboard", New With {.SortBy = "Date",.viewStatus=viewStatus})
            End If
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-table; margin-left:50px;">
            Status:
            @Html.DropDownList("selStatus", lstServiceStatus, New With {.onchange = "javascript:selectViewStatus(this);"})
        </div>
    </div>

    @For Each item In Model
```

The bulk of the formatting goes on, then the wrap up, saving the ID.  The other windows are called from this page, this is the end of it.

```
    function saveField(th, SrvId) {
        $.post("saveServiceField", {
            FieldName: th.id,
            Value: th.value,
            SrvId: SrvId
        }, function (data) { th.value = data; });
    }

    function selectViewStatus(th) {
        if (getquerystring()["SortBy"] != null) {
            window.location = "/Roster/Dashboard?SortBy=" + getquerystring()["SortBy"] + "&viewStatus=" + th.value;
        }
        else {
            window.location = "/Roster/Dashboard?viewStatus=" + th.value;
        }
    }


    function getquerystring() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
</script>
```

The WallDisplays are almost identical.

The difference between them here:

**WallDisplay1:**

```
<div id="divBoard">
    <div style="margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;">
        <div style="display: inline-table; margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px">
            Sort by:
            @If ViewBag.sortby = "Date" Then
                @Html.ActionLink("Location", "WallDisplay", New With {.SrvId = Guid.Empty, .SortBy = "Location"})
                @<span style="font-weight: bold">/ Date</span> 
            Else
                @<span style="font-weight: bold">Location /</span> 
                @Html.ActionLink("Date", "WallDisplay", New With {.SrvId = Guid.Empty, .SortBy = "Date"})
            End If
            <input type="hidden" id="hSortBy" value="@ViewBag.SortBy" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hLastSrvId" value="@ViewBag.LastSrvId" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hRefreshTime" value="@ViewBag.RefreshTime" />
             Page @ViewData("currentpage") of @ViewData("totalpage") - Refresh in <span id="countdown_text" style="font-weight: bold">@ViewData("RefreshTime1")</span>  Seconds
             <script type="text/javascript">countdown_init(@ViewData("RefreshTime1"))</script>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function loadWall() {
            var str = '/Roster/WallDisplay?SrvId=' + $('#hLastSrvId').attr('value') + '&SortBy=' + $('#hSortBy').attr('value');
            var t = setTimeout("window.location = '" + str + "'", $('#hRefreshTime').attr('value'));
        }
    </script>
    @For Each item In Model
```

**WallDisplay2:**

```
  <input type="hidden" id="hSortBy" value="@ViewBag.SortBy" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hLastSrvId" value="@ViewBag.LastSrvId" />
            <input type="hidden" id="hRefreshTime" value="@ViewBag.RefreshTime" />


    <div id="divBoard" >
    <div style="margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;">
        <div style="display:inline-table; margin:0px 0px 4px 0px">
            Sort by: 
            @If ViewBag.sortby = "Date" Then
                @Html.ActionLink("Location", "WallDisplay", New With {.SrvId = Guid.Empty, .SortBy = "Location"})
                @<span style="font-weight:bold">/ Date</span> 
            Else
                @<span style="font-weight:bold">Location /</span> 
                @Html.ActionLink("Date", "WallDisplay", New With {.SrvId = Guid.Empty, .SortBy = "Date"})
End If
           Page @ViewData("currentpage2") of @ViewData("totalpage2") - Refresh in <span id="countdown_text" style="font-weight: bold">@ViewData("RefreshTime2")</span>  Seconds
             <script type="text/javascript">countdown_init(@ViewData("RefreshTime2"))</script>
        </div>
    </div>
@If  ViewData("requiredSecondScree")=False Then
    @<strong>All Services are on the first screen...</strong>
Else
      @<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function loadWall() {
        var str = '/Roster/WallDisplay2?SrvId=' + $('#hLastSrvId').attr('value') + '&SortBy=' + $('#hSortBy').attr('value');
        var t = setTimeout("window.location = '" + str + "'", $('#hRefreshTime').attr('value'));
    }
</script>           
    For Each item In Model
```

**update Note:** All references to LastSrvId are shown in the code already posted.

**Here are the scripts.**

[image: Javascript]

I will quickly update this question with any more relevant information or code upon request.

UPDATE:  Apologies for the abundance of code:

**JScript1.js**  The only instance I could find in the project of "loadWall" that isn't already shown above.

```
var wall1Object = null;

var screenRefresher = {
    wallObject: null,

    setWall1Object: function (obj) {
        this.wallObject = obj;
        alert(this.wallObject);
        wall1Object = obj;
    },

    getWall: function () {
        alert(wall1Object);
    },

    reloadWall1Object: function () {
        console.log(wall1Object);
        if (this.wallObject != null) {
            this.wallObject.location.reload();
            return true;
        }
    }
};
var setWall1Object = function (obj) {
    wall1Object = obj;
    alert(wall1Object);
};
var reloadWall1Object = function () {
    //    wall1Object.location.reload();
    alert(wall1Object);
};
```

Comment: What about your controller code?  I suspect your model isn't being populated correctly in your WallDisplay2.  What are you using a different action for that?

Comment: I suspect the controller as well, but since the project was inherited, I don't know where to find it.  There isn't a folder for controller in the project.  There is a view folder.  As far as wallDisplay 2, it has a separate url, I don't know if that's why it was designed that way.  All the code for those displays is listed, apart from the actual row formatting, columns etc.  I am new to asp.net as well,so this is difficult to find names, everything is set dynamically

Comment: The part I can't seem to figure out, is where in the code, does the parameter ServicesPerPage get passed to the controller.  If I could find that, I think I'd be able to sort it out.

Comment: Search the project for a "RosterController".  You could also search for "WallDisplay2". You've posted a good bit of code, but your issue is in the model being passed to that View from the controller, so that code is important. Other stuff...I see the "loadWall" javascript function, but don't see it used anywhere in the code you posted.  You also mention "ServicesPerPage", but no code posted references that.

Comment: ServicesPerPage is the parameter name in the database this is bound to.  Its in SQL.  I don't see any "select from dbo.DRParameters " , name of the table containing the parameter. Or any sign of where it's bound in code.  Even if it was bound using visual studio features, you'd think there would be some code generated.

Comment: Could be retrieved using a user function, stored proc, Entity Framework, or data access compiled into a DLL that you can't see. Just no way to tell without seeing the controller code.

Comment: Is is possible it's being controlled in a javascript or jquery?  The problem with finding it, from what I can see, is that ASP.NET is awesome and is capable of creating this code dynamically, so the variable names aren't unique.  If my logic could tell me, I'd say that WallDisplay1 is controlled using the parameter, and WallDisplay2 was added after the initial scope of the project required "6" ServicesPerPage.  The original designer might have just said, "we can just start Wall2 on record 7"

Comment: I found some references to the actual database table in the BIN folder, under Work1.dll, and work1.xml.  I'm looking deeper into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long reading of your question i think this is cause of your problem if you can find this in your project you will see the controller code and also the logic of how pages are split based on this value.

```
@ViewBag.LastSrvId
```

Find `ViewBag.LastSrvId` in your project and you will get in controller code and there you can see the logic setting page number. `I have seen your code and i can see that page is refreshed based on this viewbag value passed as query string to controller "Roster/WallDisplay2" and in this controller there would be all logic of how your pages will be shown`.

**Update**

Your controller folder is not in the project it may be written separately and included in project as dll file that's why you are unable to locate Controller code and Controller folder.

Comment: I will look at that right now.  That was my first thought, but then I was lead to think it was what generates the URL, concatenated with the sort type.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like all references to that are as shown in WallDisplay1 & WallDisplay2.

Comment: Is it possible that the controller be located in the "\bin" folder?

Comment: Yes this is possible but if it was written separately in another project.

Comment: You are finding this in whole project ?

Comment: updated question with notes per discussion, and will look into the source code to make sure I'm not missing the controller.

Answer (score 1):

From everything I have looked at, I really think your problem lies in the `WallDisplay2` action in the Roster Controller.  Somewhere in there, it's pulling the data incorrectly based on your ServicesPerPage.

Your Controllers don't need to be in a "Controller" folder in order to work.  They could be in a DLL or another folder.  It just needs to be named something like this, which hoping that helps you to find it.

```
public class RosterController : Controller
```

The Action may not be `WallDisplay1` or `WallDisplay2` like what you're looking for.  You may find those used like this as well:

```
public ActionResult NewAction()
{
  return View("WallDisplay2");
}
```

Also, take a look at the value of `@ViewBag.LastSrvId` that gets written out to the following HTML field.  Make sure that changes when you update your "ServicesPerPage" and reload from the Dashboard.  If it's the same, then it's possible that value isn't being calculated using the "ServicesPerPage".

```
<input type="hidden" id="hLastSrvId" value="@ViewBag.LastSrvId" />
```

Lastly, if you're finding your DB access code in a DLL and the Controller in a DLL without the source code, you may be better off just rewriting the code to implement paging so it works correctly if more services get added.  Keying off last LastSrvId will end up causing the same issue when you reload WallDisplay2 and a service has been added to your previous page depending on the sort.

Comment: Rewriting it would be a good option, but the client wants it only modified.  Tracking down the project source code is the way I have to go.